# slow MongoDB with an easy query

Tags: mysql, mongodb

I am a MongoDB starter and I have a small problem 
a simple query like :

```
db.table.find ( { "text" : /a/ , "nb_ret" : { "$gt" : 2 } } )
```

took like 5min before giving the results

In my database I have like 53 millions line

And my server is :

`Intel Xeon E3 1225v2 , 4 c / 4 t , 3.2 GHz+ , ram : 32 Go , disk : 2x 2 To SATA`

Is it normal ?

Comment: That's not an easy query for any database, it is an extremely difficult query, one for the regex and also I would imagine because of the indexes you have, what indexes do you have? Can you show an explain?

Comment: Perhaps you meant `/^a/` otherwise it is most certainly not easy. Or at least if the results would intend to reduce by `"nb_ret": { "$gt": 2 }` then that should be the first argument to your query with a compound index that reflects that.

Answer (score 1):

Your query is by no means an easy one, since it involves performing a match against a regular expression.

Some improvements are likely to be gained by using the new **[MongoDB text indices](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/core/index-text/)**.  E.g.,

```
db.table.ensureIndex({"text": "text"})
```

Comment: Not necessarily. Text indexes are not the general solution against a "regex" based query. They have their own performance penalties themselves, part of which is being a deliberate "fuzzy" match. This should not be considered as a "solution" without further information on the intent.

Comment: This index would not cover the $gt operator either

Comment: thank you very much the solution was i should do '2'

Comment: @user3361965 not sure if I get you there, what do you mean by "i should do '2'"?

Comment: When you mention text indexes, you should also mention how they are queried, because they will not have any effect at all unless you use an explicit text-query.